# Write newline to output text file

Tags: java, text, output, text-files, newline

I want to write the output of my program to a text file.

I can't print a newline using `\n`, all the text output seems to append the string on the same line.

Only `System.out.println()` is working.

How can I fix this?

I am not allowed to use any other built-in methods such as `System.lineSeparator()` or `("Something." + newline)`.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to advise you on how to fix your code if you would edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer 
instead of \n use \r\n and it will create new line

Comment: Sure you need to use PrintWriter object to write to your output to a file

Answer (score 0):

use Printwriter

```
 PrintWriter pw=null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(new File(path));
           pw.write(string+"\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // cannot open file
        }
finally {
            if(pw != null) pw.close();
}
```

Comment: if you cannot use string+"\n" split it to 2 pw.write